# creating exploitable .csv file for java program

Tags: java, csv, arraylist

I'm both new to JAVA and .csv file so bear with me please!
Here's my problem, i have this word file :

[image]

basically i have a theme (here Science)
a difficulty level, a question number, a question, available answers and a right answer

I would like to be able to create a .csv file that i could then exploint in a java program, i'd like to store the different themes in an arraylist, the questions and their answers in another arraylist and so on. But i don't really know what's my best option since as you can see i have different formats of questions, it can be true or false, multiple choice question, and also just a question where the user would have to answer directly with a sentence. Which means that for example in that case i wouldnt have a "available answer" field.

Thanks for any help or suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is not totally clear to me. I am assuming you want to organize some data inside a CSV that later a Java program will parse in order to execute a quiz. I am also assuming that you are struggling with how the CSV file should be organized.

**One solution**

One CSV possibility would be (assuming you don't have any comma or semicolon inside your data) :

```
question_number,theme,difficulty,question,possible_answers,correct_answer
0,Sport,Medium,Who is current leader at formula 1 championship ?, 1. Hamilton;2. Verstappen,2. Verstappen
1,Science,Easy,What does the acronym LASER stands for ?,1. Light Amplification Stimulated by Emission of Radiation;2. Light Amplification Stimulated by Emission of Rigatoni,
```

For readability :
[image: Possible CSV example]

As you saw the file is divided into different columns that are comma-separated. The possible_answers column includes itself a list of the possible answers which are semicolon-separated.
This should be easily parsable with basic Java and be coherent with the implementation that you described.

This format would not allow the use of comma or semi-columns inside the data. In case you want to allow them you might want to escape the column values using double-quotes. This process is described by the [RFC 4180 CSV standard](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4180). (The RFC 4180 standard has no official value regarding the CSV format itself but it is a commonly accepted description of it)

> 5. Each field may or may not be enclosed in double-quotes (however
>    some programs, such as Microsoft Excel, do not use double quotes
>    at all).  If fields are not enclosed with double quotes, then
>    double quotes may not appear inside the fields.  For example:
>
>    "aaa","bbb","ccc" CRLF
>    zzz,yyy,xxx
> 6. Fields containing line breaks (CRLF), double quotes, and commas
>    should be enclosed in double-quotes.  For example:
>
>    "aaa","b CRLF
>    bb","ccc" CRLF
>    zzz,yyy,xxx

**Alternative solution idea**

Assuming the maximum number of "possible_answers" is knwon, an alternative solution would have been to include some columns

> answer_1,answer_2,answer_3,answer_4

And to fill them only when necessary. This would avoid the trick of parsing a semi-column separated list of possible answers.

Comment: thank you so much for your long and clear answer! this is exactly what i was looking for. And sorry again for not making the question so clear. I'm french and i'm still struggling with technical english!